# adding axes to shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0]
\draw[fill=red,draw=none] (0,0) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.3,0.28);

\draw[fill=green,draw=none] (0.3,0) -- (1.0,0) -- (1.0,0.28) -- (0.3,0.28);

\draw[fill=blue,draw=none] (0.3,0.28) -- (0.65, 0.7) -- (0.65,0.28);

\draw[fill=yellow,draw=none] (0.65,0.28) -- (0.65, 0.7)--  (1.0, 1.0) -- (1.0,0.28);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces the following image:

[image]

I now want to add x- and y-axes that goes from 0 to 1 to this image. What I want is something along the lines of this(please ignore the right part of the image):

[image]

What would be the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

With [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) to add the axes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image]
  \fill[red]    (0.00,0.00) -- (0.30,0.0) -- (0.30,0.28);
  \fill[green]  (0.30,0.00) -- (1.00,0.0) -- (1.00,0.28) -- (0.3,0.28);
  \fill[blue]   (0.30,0.28) -- (0.65,0.7) -- (0.65,0.28);
  \fill[yellow] (0.65,0.28) -- (0.65,0.7) -- (1.00,1.00) -- (1.0,0.28);
  \addplot[domain=0:1,draw=none] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also simplified your TikZ code: `\draw[fill=<color>,draw=none]` is equivalent to `\fill[<color>]`.

The dummy `\addplot` is needed so `pgfplots` gets the correct axis range and does not discard the `\fill` commands.

The key `axis equal image` is to ensure the axis unit vectors have the same length. Many further customizations are possible, you can consult the [`pgfplots` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) for more details and ask specific questions here if you run into troubles. :-)

[image]